# What could be the source of OpenGL error 0x0500 in -[CCSprite draw] 530?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, opengl-es, uikit

I am working on a project which uses `UIKit` and `cocos2d`. It is basically a game, the game uses `cocos2d` only for game play layer and `UIKit` for other screens. Everything works fine.

But when I build run the app it shows following error message

```
OpenGL error 0x0500 in -[CCSprite draw] 530
```

on console.

I have searched for it but didn't got the problem resolved, only few thing which I came to know are that

1) This issue occurs with apps using `UIKit` and `cocos2d` together and

2) is related with `CCDirector` and using it's instance.

I have posted `viewDidAppear:` method where the director is being used -

```
- (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL) animated 
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setIdleTimerDisabled:YES];

    CCDirector *director = [CCDirector sharedDirector];

    if(!m_gameScene)
    {
        if([director isViewLoaded] == NO)
        {
            // Create the OpenGL view that Cocos2D will render to.
            CCGLView *glView = [CCGLView viewWithFrame:self.view.bounds //[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] bounds]
                                           pixelFormat:kEAGLColorFormatRGB565
                                           depthFormat:0
                                    preserveBackbuffer:NO
                                            sharegroup:nil
                                         multiSampling:NO
                                       numberOfSamples:0];

            // Assign the view to the director.
            [director setView:glView];

            // Initialize other director settings.
            [director setAnimationInterval:1.0f/60.0f];

            // always enable retina display in phone.. (image picker..code is written for it..) mradul
            if(g_mainApp->IsIPhone()){
                [director enableRetinaDisplay:YES];
            }

            //            [[CCFileUtils sharedFileUtils] setiPadSuffix:@"_ipad"];
            //            [[CCFileUtils sharedFileUtils] setiPadRetinaDisplaySuffix:@"-hd"];

            [glView setTag:kGLViewTag];
        }

        // Set the view controller as the director's delegate, so we can respond to certain events.
        director.delegate = self;

        // Add the director as a child view controller of this view controller.
        [self addChildViewController:director];

        // Add the director's OpenGL view as a subview so we can see it.
        [self.view insertSubview:director.view atIndex:1];
        //    [self.view sendSubviewToBack:director.view];

        // Finish up our view controller containment responsibilities.
        [director didMoveToParentViewController:self];

        m_gameScene = [[GameScene alloc] initWithViewController:self];
    }

    // Run whatever scene we'd like to run here.
    if(director.runningScene)
        [director replaceScene:m_gameScene];
    else
        [director runWithScene:m_gameScene];

    [director startAnimation];
 }
```

Any help regarding the issue, whether the reason why this occurs, or the way to fix it is appreciated.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: `0x0500` is the value of `GL_INVALID_ENUM`. So either your code, or something in a framework you're using, is calling an OpenGL function with an invalid enum value. You should be able to localize it by calling `glGetError()` before/after calls.